# How to solve/approach $\left(\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)^2 +\left(\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)^2=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

A problem asks me to find $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ (entire function) and $f'(z)$ if
$$u^2+e^v=1.$$

If we differentiate implicitly wrt $x$ and $y$ and apply Cauchy-Riemann, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
&2uu_x-e^vu_y=0\ \ (1)\\
&2uu_y+e^vu_x=0\ \ (2).
\end{aligned}
$$
Multiplying $\textbf{(1)}$ by $-u_y$ and $\textbf{(2)}$ by $u_x$ and if we sum them, we arrive at
$$\overbrace{e^v}^{(1-u^2)}\left[\left(\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}\right)^2 +\left(\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)^2\right]=0.$$
Thus, the trivial solution would be $u=\pm 1$ which also satisfies the partial diff. eq.. With that, applying Cauchy-Riemann once again, we finally find that $v=\text{constant}$.

I'm guessing, if this is done correctly, that the exercise wanted us to find the trivial solution and not bother with the partial diff. eq., but I was wondering how'd you even solve that; in other words, what other solutions would satisfy the initial equality/condition?

Comment: The only way the sum of squares can be zero is if each partial derivative is zero, so the trivial solution is indeed the only one.  If the right hand side were nonzero, this would be the eikonal equation.

Comment: I see, you're right: the derivative of a real function yields a real function and a sum of squared reals is 0 if and only if each real is 0.

Comment: So the correct answer would be $u$ and $v$ are constants ($u=\pm1$ is redundant).

Comment: what is that weird bracket notation thing ?